# how to know whether a particular line of code is present in the compilation unit?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to search for a particular line of code in the compilation unit. So need some input on how to go about the same.
thanks

Comment: How robust does this have to be? What if that statement is not reachable? What if the statement is reachable by Java compiler rules (which is somewhat conservative) but not reachable in practice? What if it's semantically the same but written slightly differently? Perhaps with Unicode escapes, or obfuscated with more sophisticated techniques?

Comment: i just have to search for a line of code exists or not thats it. ie kind of word search in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Do a *file search* in the whole project (or workspace) and use the file filter `*.java`. This will scan all java source files for the given phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the text or you can use the References or Declarations search from Eclipse: select the line of code, right click and then choose References or Declarations.

Very useful to find where you call a certain method or where you used some class.